# Scala Comparing time columns in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe with two columns 'time1' and 'time2' with the format : "hh:mm:ss"

I want to create a new column that is the difference between 'time1' and 'time2'.

I have tried this :

```
 df.withColumn("diff",
                  datediff(
                         to_timestamp($"time1", "hh:mm:ss"),
                         to_timestamp($"time2", "hh:mm:ss")
                          )
            )
```

But it always return 0 for diff. What is the correct way to do this ?

data sample :

```
time1, time2
05:35:30, 05:35:12
07:30:55, 02:39:10
08:35:30, 09:36:10
04:35:30, 05:33:50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the format should be "HH:mm:ss"
Second datediff only returns diff in days

So if you want a diff in minutes:

```
df.withColumn("diffs", 
     (to_timestamp('time1, "HH:mm:ss").cast("bigint") - to_timestamp('time2, "HH:mm:ss")
         .cast("bigint")) / lit(60))
```